# How to include layout in Dynamically

Tags: android

How to done the following code through dynamically.

```
    <include layout="@layout/content_android_dashboard_design" />
```

I need to include different layout when clicking user in my Slider menu items;It given below.

```
      @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_hospital) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_atm) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_feedback) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: see `ViewGroup#addView` method

Comment: Is their is any referance link

Comment: do you have SDK documentation installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider looking into fragment replacement if you want your new views to replace the old ones.

1 Declare a FrameLayout where you want the fragment to appear.

2 Make a Fragment class for each of the fragments or reuse one if they are similar looking

3 Replace the fragments using

```
 getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.<yourFrameLayoutID>, <anInstaceOfYourFragmentObject>)
    .commit()
```

You can also add it to the back stack so that your back button functionality works by using

```
.addToBackStack(null)/*before*/.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

   View childLayout = null;

// Handle navigation view item clicks here.
   int id = item.getItemId();

   if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
      childLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.where_to_include));

   } else if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {
      childLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.where_to_include));

   } else if (id == R.id.nav_hospital) {
      childLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout3, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.where_to_include));

   } else if (id == R.id.nav_atm) {
      childLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout4, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.where_to_include));

   } else if (id == R.id.nav_feedback) {
      childLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout5, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.where_to_include));

   } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
      childLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout6, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.where_to_include));

  // then add childLayout to your row
}



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```